# MYSQL - empty string == 0 problem (updates row with primary key 0 instead of insert)

Tags: mysql, string, zero

actually this already worked and i have no idea what i've changed so that i run into this problem now. Tried nearly everything.

**The case:**
I have the following query. The variable $DB-id is an empty string if the content i want to save is new. The field module_id is my primary key. What happens is that this query always updates the row with the module_id => 0.

**The problem**
Passing an empty variable as the primary key always updates row 0 instead of inserting a new one.

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO   modules_text 
                                (   
                                module_id,
                                module_content,
                                module_page_idx, 
                                module_post_id
                                )
                  VALUES        (
                                '{$DB_id}',
                                '{$content['text']}',
                                '{$content['idx']}',
                                '{$post_id}'
                                )
                  ON DUPLICATE KEY
                  UPDATE        module_content  = '{$content['text']}',
                                module_page_idx = '{$content['idx']}'
                ");
```

Does anybody have an idea how i can tell MYSQL to create a new row??? Any help is very appreciated!!!! Thank you very much!!!

Saludos Sacha!

Comment: if the primary key field a auto_increment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set your primary key field to auto increment.  An example is below.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
 id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

Comment: OH MY GOSH... I LOST THE AUTO INCREMENT... I can't believe it... Slaming my head on the table... I have no idea how that happened. But actually that was the point.

Comment: I AM FEEEEEELING SOOOOOO STUPID NOW... But really it was the easiest mistake i never looked at.

Comment: Uhm, looks like it wasn't my mistake... just looked into Github and saw who did it ;-) REVENGE!!!! No idea how... but i will give him that back... THX ! ;-P